# How do I declaratively bind 'SelectedValue' to datasource field?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I want to drive a `RadioButtonList`s `SelectedValue` property from a property in my datasource, but I'm not managing to make it work.

I have a `<asp:RadioButtonList` on my page bound to an `<asp:ObjectDataSource`. This datasource in turn provides the following model class:

```
public class CollectionWithDefault : Collection<string>
{
    CollectionWithDefault(IEnumerable<string> items, string defaultItem)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            Add(item);

        DefaultItem = defaultItem;
    }

    public string DefaultItem { get; }
}
```

Notice that this class is a standard collection of strings that also exposes which one of them is the default option.

Consider that I have the following implementation for a value provider. This is a simple in-memory implementation, but keep in mind that this could be coming from a database or any other source:

```
public static class ItemProvider
{
    public static CollectionWithDefault GetAvailableItems()
    {
        var items = new [] { "option1", "option2", "option3" };

        return new CollectionWithDefault(items, items[1]);
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server"
    ID="ItemSource"
    TypeName="MyNamespace.ItemProvider"
    SelectMethod="GetAvailableItems" />
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="ItemSource"
    SelectedValue='<%# Eval("DefaultItem") #>' />
```

I'm getting the following exception in the `Eval` call:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.'

How can I ensure that the correct radio is preselected based on the field coming from my datasource?

Changing the collection model itself to make it work is acceptable, but I can't set the `SelectedValue` from codebehind. I wanted to rely on the datasource control to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll have to do it with code behind, setting the selected index or selected value. `SelectedValue` is not a valid attribute of the `asp:RadioButtonList` control.

Comment: @wazz `SelectedValue` is definitely valid, it just doesn't show in intellisense.

Comment: I get an error: `The 'SelectedValue' property cannot be set declaratively.`

Comment: Can you share a piece of code where you are seeing this @wazz? I've never seen this error message before, and I just double checked my real production code and I can assure you `RadioButtonList` has a `SelectedValue` and that you should be able to declaratively set it.

Comment: I'm talking about in the markup, on the control. `<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" SelectedValue="asdf">`. (Plus listitems and closing tag.)

Comment: It appears that you get this error when trying to set a value directly @wazz. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580487/aspdropdownlist-in-itemtemplate-why-is-selectedvalue-attribute-allowed)]. This is not what I'm doing, since I need the value to be databound to the source using a databinding expression.

Comment: I think there's a difference. The example in the link is in an `Edit Template` and there is an existing value to be bound -- you are now editing, what is the initial value to set? As though editing a table-row. When editing, values have to be set (bound) for you to edit. But you are saying, 'here's a collection of items for the list, now I want to make *this* one the selected one.' You are declaring it; it's not bound in any way. Maybe there's a way, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Have you tried `Bind` instead of `Eval`?

Comment: Yes, `Bind()` throws the exact same exception @wazz

Comment: @wazz, FYI I found a way out of this and added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make this work seamlessly without requiring manual assignments in codebehind by extending the original `RadioButtonList` control and modifying the core databinding method to honor `ListItem` objects.

It goes something like this:

```
public class MyRadioButtonList : RadioButtonList
{
    protected override void PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable dataSource)
    {
        if (dataSource is IEnumerable<ListItem> listItems)
        {
            ...

            foreach (var listItem in listItems)
                Items.Add(listItem);

            ...
        }
        else
        {
            base.PerformDataBinding(dataSource);
        }
    }    
}
```

With this in place, it was just a matter of converting my source model into a `IEnumerable<ListItem>` on the presentation layer (easy to accomplish with an adapter/proxy implementation) and then feed these `ListItem`s to the control.

Once I got this in place, I could see my selected items reflected correctly in the UI based on the datasource field. Considering how trivial the extension is, I feel it was quite worth it :)

The same inheritance approach can probably be used for similar controls like `CheckBoxList`, which suffers from the very same limitation.

For the more adventurous folks, one could also make this work by introducing extra `DataSelectedField` and `DataEnabledField` properties in the control and using `Eval` on top of them as part of the original databinding algorithm (which already does this with `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`). I felt this would be a little bit more involved for my use case and decided to go with a simpler override, but it is definitely a valid approach that could even live along my proposed solution for an even more robust `RadioButtonList`.